# Python: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Intento graficar una funcion de una curva par vs velocidad de un motor de inducción, pero me salta el error del título, estoy tratando de generar la gráfica para poder ver su curva. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error ó qué estoy haciendo mal? el error me salta en el bucle `for`, en la ecuacion de torque(ii)

Existe un código en `MATLAB` que es por el que me estoy guiando, donde ya muestra esa caracteristica pero debo hacerlo en `python`.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#valores requeridos del programa

r1 = 0.641 #resistencia del estator.
r2 = 0.332 #resistencia del rotor.
x1 = 1.106 #reactancia del estator.
x2 = 0.464 #reactancia del rotor.
xm = 26.3 #reactancia del circuito tanque.

voltaje_fase = 460/math.sqrt(3)

n_sincronismo = 1800
n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

#Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.

vth = voltaje_fase * (xm /math.sqrt(r1**2 + (x1 + xm)**2))

zth = ((xm*1j)*(r1 + x1*1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm)*1j)
rth = zth.real
xth = zth.imag

#Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.

s = np.arange(0, 51, 0.001)
nm = (1 - s)*n_sincronismo

for ii in range(1,51):

  torque(ii) = ((3*vth**2*r2)/s(ii)) / (n_sincronismo_rad*(rth +
  (r2*2)/s(ii))**2 + (xth + x2)**2)
  plt.plot(nm,torque)
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: En un typo en principio, en Python/NumPy no se indiza usando paréntesis, eso indica "llamar a" (ejecutar función o método, instanciar clase,etc). Para indizar se deben usar `[]`, no es `torque(ii)` o `s(ii)`, es `torque[ii]` y  `s[ii]`.

Comment: Aun corrigiendo los typos la lista torque no está definida antes del for y se china el repl, definiendola fuera me da _out of range_ cuando pasa por el bucle. Habria que pythonizar un poco ese bucle y aun así no se si el plot deberia de estar dentor del bucle...

Comment: vale, ya se porque da out of range, porque está intenando acceder a un indice que no existe porque la lista está vacia, Necesita un `.append()` o una comprensión de lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas:

- En Python no se indiza usando paréntesis como en Matlab. Se debe usar `[]`. Los paréntesis detrás de un identificador se usan para ejecutar o llamar algún objeto que sea "callable". Es decir, para ejecutar una función o método, instanciar una clase, etc.

  Cuando haces `torque(ii) = ...` el intérprete asimila que `torque` es una función y que la llamas pasando `ii` como argumento, además intentas asignar un valor al retorno de la función, lo cual no es posible. La sintaxis adecuada es por tanto `torque[ii]` y `s[ii]`.
- `torque` no está definido antes del `for`, debes crear el array vacío con las mismas dimensiones que `s`. Deberías hacer algo como:

  ```
  torque = np.zeros_like(nm)
  for ii in range(...):
      ...
  ```
- Debes crear la gráfica una vez calculados todos los elementos de torque, no en cada iteración. si haces eso te crea una gráfica por cada iteración bloqueando el ciclo entre iteraciones (`show` es bloquenate, por lo que no itera de nuevo hasta cerrar la ventana).
- El rango no debe ser `(1, 51)`. Ten en cuenta que `s`, `torque` y `nm` no tienen 51 elementos, tienen 51000. Esto se debe a que  con `np.arange(0, 51, 0.001)` indicas que se cree un array desde cero hasta 51 (no incluido) yendo de 0.001 en 0.001 (paso). Es decir:

  ```
  [0.0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003,... , 50.999]
  ```

  **Recuerda siempre que en Python el primer índice de cualquier objeto indizable es el 0, no el 1**.

  ```
  for ii in range(1, torque.shape[0]):  # No indiza sobre el primer elemento

  for ii in range(0, torque.shape[0]):  # Indiza sobre el primer elemento
  ```

  Dicho esto, no uses un ciclo `for` en este caso, es muy ineficiente. Aprovecha las posibilidades de vectorización de operaciones que te ofrece NumPy, como haces cuando  calculas `nm`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Valores requeridos del programa
r1 = 0.641  # resistencia del estator.
r2 = 0.332  # resistencia del rotor.
x1 = 1.106  # reactancia del estator.
x2 = 0.464  # reactancia del rotor.
xm = 26.3   # reactancia del circuito tanque.

voltaje_fase = 460/np.sqrt(3)

n_sincronismo = 1800
n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

# Calculamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.
vth = voltaje_fase * (xm / np.sqrt(r1**2 + (x1 + xm)**2))
zth = ((xm*1j)*(r1 + x1*1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm)*1j)
rth = zth.real
xth = zth.imag

# Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.
s = np.arange(0.001, 51, 0.001)
nm = (1 - s) * n_sincronismo
torque = (
    ((3 * vth ** 2 * r2) / s) /
    (n_sincronismo_rad * (rth + (r2 * 2) / s) ** 2 + (xth + x2) ** 2)
)

plt.plot(nm, torque)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota**: el 0 no debe en principio incluirse dentro del rango de los valores de `s` dado que ocasiona una división entre 0 al calcular `torque` y el consiguiente warning por parte de NumPy.

Comment: gracias amigo, ya lo había resuelto pero tus aclaraciones sirvieron bastante, un saludo muchas gracias.